# Cefsharp chromium browser doesn't load only first time on Windows server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp

Hi i have wpf desktop application. I am using cefsharp.wpf chromium browser to open web page. I added cefsharp from nuget pacakge manager (version 87.1.132). it does work very well in my system (Windows 10, 64 bit os).

But when i run my exe in client's environment (windows 2012 r2,64 bit os), strange thing happens, which is browser doesn't load only when i try first time. basically i have a button & on button click i do open one window which has cefsharp chromium browser in it. so when window opens first time browser doesn't load anything. now if i close window and open it again browser will redirect to my url . only first time browser doesnt load. after first time it does load everytime until i close exe and try again.

if i close exe and open it again and try to open that window, again browser will not load anything. then i close that window and try again browser will work perfectly.

What i am doing is very simple i have browser in xaml file in one window, and in cs file when window is loaded i am assigning one address to browser and that's it.

in xaml
`<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" />`

in xaml.cs on window loaded

`browser.address = url;` // i am using [www.xero.com](http://www.xero.com) login url (which i dont think should matter as it does work second time).

can anybody tell me what's happening here ?

I have debug.log file for cefsharp which says:

```
[0317/231700.441:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(431)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0317/231700.442:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(539)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[0317/231700.537:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(150)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0317/231700.542:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(168)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[0317/232456.104:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1086)] locale resources are not loaded
[0317/232456.105:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(1086)] locale resources are not loaded
[0317/232456.421:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(431)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0317/232456.422:ERROR:alloy_main_delegate.cc(539)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[0317/232458.805:INFO:CONSOLE(333)] "Refused to connect to 'https://analytics.google.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-Q622B96ZEQ&gtm=2oe330&_p=609855886&sr=1366x768&_gaz=1&ul=en-us&cid=1821054078.1615983899&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.xero.com%2Fidentity%2Fuser%2Flogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Fidentity%252Fconnect%252Fauthorize%252Fcallback%253Fresponse_type%253Dcode%2526client_id%253DC35C4505FBEA4D31A8E5A0404FDA9E0E%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%2526scope%253Dopenid%252520profile%252520email%252520files%252520accounting.transactions%252520accounting.tra...2520accounting.journals.read%252520accounting.settings%252520accounting.settings.read%252520accounting.contacts%252520accounting.contacts.read%252520accounting.attachments%252520accounting.attachments.read%252520offline_access%252520payroll.employees%252520payroll.employees.read%2526state%253D108Sydney%2526code_challenge%253D3b5GLmW09QQB-C4Sq8ud0M0sEYpqFr5_KY20way8l1U%2526code_challenge_method%253DS256&dt=Login%20%7C%20Xero%20Accounting%20Software&sid=1615983898&sct=1&seg=0&en=page_view&_fv=1&_nsi=1&_ss=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https://browsercheck.xero.com https://edge.xero.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://telemetry.ext.platformdevelopment.xero.com https://api.mixpanel.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://p.adsymptotic.com https://*.fls.doubleclick.net https://*.linkedin.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://identity.xero.com https://login.xero.com https://go.xero.com https://static.xero.com 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
", source: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-Q622B96ZEQ&l=dataLayer&cx=c (333)
[0317/232458.806:INFO:CONSOLE(333)] "Refused to connect to 'https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-Q622B96ZEQ&cid=1821054078.1615983899&gtm=2oe330&aip=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https://browsercheck.xero.com https://edge.xero.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://telemetry.ext.platformdevelopment.xero.com https://api.mixpanel.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://p.adsymptotic.com https://*.fls.doubleclick.net https://*.linkedin.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://identity.xero.com https://login.xero.com https://go.xero.com https://static.xero.com 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
", source: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-Q622B96ZEQ&l=dataLayer&cx=c (333)
[0317/232458.819:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'https://www.google.com.au/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&t=sr&slf_rd=1&_r=4&tid=G-Q622B96ZEQ&cid=1821054078.1615983899&gtm=2oe330&aip=1&z=174504349' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://browsercheck.xero.com https://edge.xero.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://telemetry.ext.platformdevelopment.xero.com https://api.mixpanel.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://p.adsymptotic.com https://*.fls.doubleclick.net https://*.linkedin.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://identity.xero.com https://login.xero.com https://go.xero.com https://static.xero.com".
", source: https://login.xero.com/identity/user/login?...
```

i verified locale folder it is same as it is in my local system. And it says refused to connect as it violates something.. then it shouldn't work when i try second time. So i am totally confused what's happening here. can anybody tell me whats wrong here ?.

Help !

Comment: Did you set tge locale folder programatically? Does en-us.pak exist in the locales folder? Not a whole lot of information to go on here, the log says it cannot load the pak file which is required. If the file exists then I'd suggest checking the permission. If it has read access then I'd use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to see what's going on at a low level.

Comment: @amaitland No i didnt set the folder programatically, but if theres any issue how does it work second time?

Comment: As I've never seen or had reports of anything similar, at least that I remember. It's hard to say. Missing locales will cause you problems, so I'd try fix that first and see what you get. CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers, your welcome to ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php for a second opinion.

Comment: Is the server running Citrix?

Comment: @amaitland i didn't initialize Cef as i thought it isn't necessary as it was working proper in my system. Added the answer.

Comment: It should only be nessicary to call Cef.Initialize if you need to provide custom settings. The following should be called otherwise https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/88/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L517 As I don't have an example that reproduces the problem I don't know what's happening in your case. If manually calling Cef.Initialize resolves the problem then that's an easy workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very basic. I hadn't initialized Cef. As it was working without it second time. I did initialize it in App.xaml.cs when application is starting and now it does work fine everytime. Although i still wonder why it was working (if i load window second time without initializing Cef).

Here's what i added.

```
 if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
                        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings(), performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        ErrorLogger.LogError(ex.GetType().ToString(), ex, GetType().FullName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                    }
                }
```

As it was working very well in my system without initializing Cef i thought it isn't compulsory to do that. But it seems that it is necessary.